# Spring MVC Tiles jsp page not load properly

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I'm working on a **Spring MVC** project using **Tiles**.When I run app,I get no error.But jsp page is not loaded properly like below

[image]

When i look at this page's source,i can see layout.jsp and home.jsp codes are loaded.But as you see above,the page shows jsp tags only.

Development Environment

```
-> Spring MVC 3.2.8 Release
-> Apache Tiles 2.2.1 
    tiles-core-2.2.1.jar
    tiles-template-2.2.1.jar
    tiles-jsp-2.2.1.jar
    tiles-servlet-2.2.1.jar
    tiles-api-2.2.1.jar
    tiles-request-api-1.0.1.jar
```

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">      

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
        template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/template1/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="menu"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="menu"
               preparer="menuController"
               template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/components/menu.jsp">
    </definition>
    <definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

**layout.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page language="java"  contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib  uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<html>
<head>

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
   <title><tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url 
           value='/resources/css/style.css'/>"/> 

</head>
<body>
   <div id="layout">
    <div id="header">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="leftContent">
           <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
        </div>
        <div id="rightContent">
           <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<%@ page language="java"  contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 

    <c:if test="${!empty kodListe}">
        <h3 >En Son Eklenenler</h3>

        <c:forEach items="${kodListe}" var="kod">
            <form:form action="kod" method="POST">
            <table>
            <tr> 
               <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="kodId" value="${kod.kodId}" />
                  <input value="${kod.kodBaslik}" type="submit"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     ${kod.kodEkleyenKullanici.kullaniciAd}
                </td>
                 <td>
                       ${kod.kodEklemeTarihi}
                 </td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            </form:form>
        </c:forEach>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>

        </property>
```

How to solve the problem?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was tiles config with servlet mapping in the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I use `/*`, **home.jsp** loads tiles configuration correctly,but without css and images.

In the case `/`, **home.jsp** does not load tiles configuration and shows up only the codes which was defined only in home.jsp

I found the solution  [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/76012-spring-tiles-clean-friendly-urls)
  To solve the problem as a  Spring sample that uses tuckey to do url writing (https://src.springframework.org/svn/...ebapp/WEB-INF/ ),I added filter and filter mapping which uses `/*` url mapping and changed **appServlet** url pattern to `/`

**web.xml**

```
 <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->

    <filter>
            <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
```

I removed this from `web.xml`

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And lastly I changed 
 **servlet-context.xml**

```
<!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "home" view -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />
```

Then everything start to work.Hope this help another stackoverflow user